# Any shorter way to add attributes to specified elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming I have a wide table with many columns, and I want to add `colspan=2` to:

<strike>`td#2, td#10, td#15`</strike>

`td#3, td#11, td#16`

Do I have to do it specifically:

```
$("table td").eq(2).attr('colspan','2')
$("table td").eq(10).attr('colspan','2')
$("table td").eq(15).attr('colspan','2')
```

Or should I use `filter()`?

Is there any shorter way?

Comment: You're missing some `'` quotes on the second parameter, typo?

Comment: Note that `index` is zero based so the second `td` is `eq(1)`, the tenth is `eq(9)` and so on.

Comment: 6 answers, 5 10k+ reputation users, 13 upvotes and 31 views. Still no one can edit the title

Comment: @Alex, title edits are usually minor (and I guess we were more focused on answering the question :) Your point still stands, but you could have considered the rest of the question in your previous edit. See [this post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/) from our fearless co-founder for the rationale behind this.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I beg to disagree about title edits being minor ones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
$('table').find('td:eq(2), td:eq(10), td:eq(15)').prop('colspan', 2);
```

(I'd use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` I think, but I need to make sure :-) (*edit* yup it's a real property)

Note that the above would work, but those jQuery extended search qualifiers like `:eq()` can slow down the selection process. It might be faster to use a separate filter step after selecting just the cells.

Also note that that selection (like your original code) finds the 2nd, 10th, and 15th cells *in the whole table*.  If you wanted to set the property of the 2nd, 10th, and 15th cells on each row, you'd probably want something different.

Comment: yeah you right it is a dom property of td. just wanted to get the idea of doing it shorter.

Comment: If it's set in the HTML, like colspan often is, I'd think it's an attribute you'd like to change and that attr() would be the correct method ??

Comment: @adeneo not really, or at least *usually* not.  Once it's in the DOM, it's a property, and by definition JavaScript code like this is operating on the DOM.  It's the set of properties of DOM objects that control behavior/presentation, not the attributes.  That used to be kind-of fuzzy in jQuery, but the 1.9 release has stiffened the distinction between the functions. (That said, `.attr()` *might* work anyway; I'm not sure here.)

Comment: @adeneo well `.attr()` does indeed work just fine here.  One of these days I'll figure out exactly what the semantics are :-)

Comment: Yes it does, checked it myself. As far as the difference, other than the obvious cases and the recomandations from the jQuery site, I never know which one to use myself, but in those cases usually both will work just fine?

Comment: @adeneo I think that it's things like `checked`, `disabled`, and `selected` where it gets weird.  Again, I just haven't taken the time to figure out for myself what's going on; the explanations in the jQuery docs don't do it for me :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
$("td:eq(2), td:eq(10), td:eq(15)", "table").prop('colspan',2);
```

is i think the shortest possible way.

Comment: As i stated on the OP, `td` elements 2, 10 and 15 are `eq(1)`, `eq(9)` and `eq(14)` respectively. +1 nontheless.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Yeah, missed that detail. All concentration was on counting the bytes of the selector string. :-)

Comment: @techfoobar: Your first indexes were correct. You should have just stayed using the same eq values as OP as they obviously did what OP wanted, seeing OP only asked for improving the syntax, it was the added text above OP's code which was wrong.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - Right. I see it has been updated in the question as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("table td").filter(':eq(2), :eq(10), :eq(15)').attr('colspan',2);
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to multiple selectors, you can invoke the form of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) that takes a function and write:

```
$("table td").attr("colspan", function(index) {
    return index == 2 || index == 10 || index == 15 ? "2" : undefined;
});
```

(You can use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) equally well here, since its setter form also supports taking a function and the `colspan` attribute directly maps to the DOM property of the same name.)

Answer (score 0):

You can optimise your code as below. Rather than jumping into DOM and searching `$("table td")` 3 times cache the it into a variable and use it.

```
var td = $("table td");

td.eq(2).attr('colspan',2);
td.eq(10).attr('colspan',2);
td.eq(15).attr('colspan',2);
```

Else you can do something like

```
$("td:eq(2), td:eq(10), td:eq(15)", "table").attr('colspan',2);
```

Else

```
$("table").filter('td:eq(2), td:eq(10), td:eq(15)').attr('colspan',2);
```